# Typeahead dropdown list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering, typeahead.js

I have an API that returns list with three fields. EG ['Michał', 6, 'Michal']. First field is name full name with diacritics used in my language, second is an ID and thrid is full name with removed diacritics.

Now I want to type in my select box Michal and I want my searchbox to find either Michal and Michał. Actually I have done it by removing dacritics from select-box input.

Now if I  input Michal it shows Michal but full name is Michał and if I type Michał it says NO RESULT but filters properly.

How can I change my typeahead/select-box so it shows also Michał or Michal in dropdown after I write Michał.

Comment: As I understand it's something like filtering in typeahead with an ignore-polish (like ignore-case)?

Comment: Yeah something like that

Comment: Try angular-chosen: https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/dYyzgL9B1i06mJCePTwF?p=preview

html:

```
  <div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

    <h4>Static arrays</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
   <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="person as person.pplname for person in persons | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">

 </div>
```

js:

```
  angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    function TypeaheadCtrl($scope) {

      $scope.selected = undefined;
      $scope.persons = [{name:"michal", pplname:"michał", id:1},
      {name:"janek", pplname:"janek", id:5},
      {name:"marek", pplname:"marek", id:6},
      {name:"slawek", pplname:"sławek", id:7},
      {name:"olek", pplname:"olek", id:8},
      {name:"tomek", pplname:"tome", id:9}];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! :)
After that I had some other issue but resolved that. Thanks!